# rxjs operators with multiple inserts

Tags: angular, rxjs6

How would I go about using rxjs in Angular 6 for inserting an item, then after insert I need to upload different types of files to different endpoints with the new item id as a child key without having to nest all these calls.

```
createItemWithAttachments(data:any)
{    
   this.itemService.insert(data.item).subscribe((newItem:Item)=>{       
        //attachment type 1s 
        if(data.attachmentType1.length > 0){    
         this.attachmentService.upload(data.attachmentType1, 
            "type1", newItem.id).subscribe(newAttachment=>{

         });    
    }    

    //attachment type 2s 
    if(data.attachmentType2.length > 0){    
         this.attachmentService.upload(data.attachmentType2, 
             "type2", newItem.id).subscribe(newAttachment=>{    

         });    
    }    
    });    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way would be to use `mergeMap` together with a `merge` and `last` to get the last emitted value from the merge. You have to determine what to put inside the `of()`. This should be either `undefined`/`void 0`/`null` if you are returning an object from the `upload` call, or an empty array `[]` if you are returning an array from the upload:

```
createItemWithAttachments({ item, attachmentType1: type1, attachmentType2: type2 }): void {
  this.itemService.insert(item).pipe(
    mergeMap(({ id }: Item) => {
      const mergeUpload = [
        ...(type1.length ? [this.attachmentService.upload(type1, "type1", id)] : []),
        ...(type2.length ? [this.attachmentService.upload(type2, "type2", id)] : [])
      ];

      return mergeUpload.length ? merge(...mergeUpload) : of([]);
    }),
    last()
  ).subscribe((newAttachments) => {

  });
}
```

Comment: I'm actually returning an item from the upload since it maps a bunch of other properties, is there a way to get the last call that completed?

Comment: the newAttachments will contain an array with the responses of the merge array in that order. Is that not enough?

Comment: I have the attachments service returning an Item with the attachments nested so was wondering how to get the last item that was completed in mergemap

Comment: thank you very much, I'm catching on to this now, rxjs is challenging.

Comment: @Fab you are welcome, and you are right. The amount of operators are overwhelming! Good luck :)

Answer (score 2):

I think there is multiple ways of going about this, but one way could be something like:

```
this.itemService.insert(data.item)
    .pipe(
        take(1),
        mergeMap((newItem:Item) => {
            const attachmentUpdateObservables = [];
            if(data.attachmentType1.length > 0){
              attachmentUpdateObservables.push(this.attachmentService.upload(data.attachmentType1, "type1", newItem.id));
            }

            if(data.attachmentType2.length > 0){
              attachmentUpdateObservables.push(this.attachmentService.upload(data.attachmentType2, "type2", newItem.id));
            }

            return combineLatest(attachmentUpdateObservables);

        })
    .subscribe(newAttachments => {
        // Do something
    });
```

Comment: I have a red line under mergeMap, it wants ObservableInput, I'm trying to understand mergeMap so not sure what I'm missing yet.

Type 'OperatorFunction<{}, [{}, any]>' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.

I think combineLatest is the culprit, mergeMap wants a return of Observable

Comment: if guess I need to wrap combineLastest  like so:

  return of(combineLatest(attachmentUpdateObservables));

Comment: combineLatest should return an Observable, so it should not be necessary to wrap it in an of().

I guess the error could  be because "attachmentUpdateObservables" could be an empty array. Not sure how combineLatest handles an empty array, but looks like PierreDuc had a solution to that with "return merge.length ? forkJoin(merge) : of([]); ".

Another potential reason could be if combineLatest is imported from the wrong place. Should be "import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs'.

Comment: I just realized I had imported it from import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs/operators'; which returns OperaterFunction, I changed it to import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs'; and it does return an observable. Thanks very much.